# How to get around using global variables in a C program?

Tags: c

I am currently working on a C project where the use of global variables is banned, and I have a few variables that need to be modified and passed to several functions. I asked if I can have my variables in main and pass them to the functions (and return them respectively) and I was told yes, but there may be easier ways to do so.
For example if my variables are:

```
length = 9;
result[245];
```

Then they both need to be passed to several functions to either be modified or used in the functions.
I can't think of an "easier way" to do this that does not require globals; any ideas? I was thinking maybe a #DEFINE for length, but length will be modified, and as far as I know you cant modify values in #DEFINE statements.

Comment: You can combine multiple variables into a `struct` and pass `struct`s instead of individual variables. Especially useful if multiple variables are actually talking about the same "thing", but different aspects of it.

Answer (score 5):

#### Method 0:

Return new values and assign them in the calling routine:

```
int foo(int length)
{
    …               // Do work.
    length += 17;   // Modify length as needed.
    …               // Do work.
    return length   // Return updated length.
}


int main(void)
{
    int length = 9;
    length = foo(stuff, length);
    …
}
```

#### Method 1:

Pass pointers to the objects:

```
void foo(int *length, char result[])
{
    …               // Do work.
    *length += 17;  // Modify length as needed, using pointer.
    …               // Do work.
}

int main(void)
{
    int length = 9;
    char result[245];
    foo(&length, result);
    …
}
```

Note that arrays are automatically passed “by reference”: When an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof`, as the operand of unary `&`, or as a string literal initializing an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. And a function parameter declaration of an array is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to the element type. So, given the above code, any changes that `foo` makes to the contents of `result` will affect the original array.

### Adding Structures

If there are many objects to manage, you can group them into structures:

```
struct Parameters
{
    int length;
    char result[245];
};
```

Then you can use the two methods above with this. Method 0:

```
struct Parameters foo(struct Parameters P)
{
    …               // Do work.
    P.length += 17; // Modify parameters as needed.
    P.result[i] = q;
    …               // Do work.
    return P;       // Return updated parameters.
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Parameters P = { 9, "initial contents of result" };
    P = foo(P);
    …
}
```

Method 1:

```
void foo(struct Parameters *P)
{
    …                // Do work.
    P->length += 17; // Modify parameters as needed, using pointer.
    P->result[i] = q;
    …                // Do work.
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Parameters P = { 9, "initial contents of result" };
    foo(&P);
    …
}
```

Method 0 may force the compiler to make a copy of the parameters, so, if they are large, prefer to use method 1.

Comment: Obviously your code examples are not meant to be compilable and the explanations are 
sound, but `foo()` in Adding Structures/Method 0 returns `struct Parameters`, not `int`. Likely to be pretty confusing to the OP.